Class private methods are not enabled. Please add `@babel/plugin-transform-private-methods` to your configuration
Хоть я и определил плагин @babel/plugin-transform-private-methods, он почему-то не заработал
vite.config.mts
/// <reference types='vitest' />
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { nxViteTsPaths } from '@nx/vite/plugins/nx-tsconfig-paths.plugin';

export default defineConfig({
  root: __dirname,
  cacheDir: '../../node_modules/.vite/apps/web',

  server: {
    port: 4200,
    host: 'localhost',
  },

  preview: {
    port: 4300,
    host: 'localhost',
  },

  optimizeDeps: {
    include: [
      '@emotion/react', 
      '@emotion/styled', 
      '@mui/material/Tooltip'
    ],
  },
  plugins: [react({
    jsxImportSource: '@emotion/react',
    babel: {
      plugins: ['@emotion/babel-plugin', "@babel/plugin-transform-private-methods"],
    },
  }), nxViteTsPaths()],

  // Uncomment this if you are using workers.
  // worker: {
  //  plugins: [ nxViteTsPaths() ],
  // },

  build: {
    outDir: '../../dist/apps/web',
    reportCompressedSize: true,
    commonjsOptions: {
      transformMixedEsModules: true,
    },
  },
  
  test: {
    globals: true,
    cache: {
      dir: '../../node_modules/.vitest',
    },
    environment: 'jsdom',
    include: ['src/**/*.{test,spec}.{js,mjs,cjs,ts,mts,cts,jsx,tsx}'],
    reporters: ['default'],
    coverage: {
      reportsDirectory: '../../coverage/apps/web',
      provider: 'v8',
      exclude: [
        'server.ts',      // Added these to be excluded from coverage
        'handler.ts',
      ],
    },
  },
});


jest.config.ts
import { getJestProjects } from '@nx/jest';

export default {
  projects: getJestProjects(),
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+[^esm]\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx)$",
    "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$",
  ],
  transform: {
    '^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)': '@nx/react/plugins/jest',
    '^.+\\.[tj]sx?$': ['babel-jest', { presets: ['@nx/react/babel'] },],
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '@diary-app/shared': '<rootDir>/libs/web/shared/src/index.ts',
    'shared-backend': '<rootDir>/libs/backend/shared/src/index.ts'
  },
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["@testing-library/jest-dom", "./jest.setup.ts"],
  setupFiles: ['./jest.polyfills.js'],
  testEnvironmentOptions: {
    customExportConditions: [''],
  },
  
};







